# Как сортировать полученные из postgesql данные

Tags: java

Есть база данных postgresql, есть java класс который показывает все данные, как сортировать как чтобы, раньше показанные данные повторно не показывались, а только новые добавленные данные показывались

Comment: Покажите как вы получаете данные из базы

Comment: Это нужна не сортировка на клиенте, а отбор на сервере. Где, кстати, должен храниться признак, что показано (данному конкретному юзеру, вероятно), а что нет.

Comment: если сделать так чтобы раньше показанные данные повторно не показывались, то как пользователь может определить показывались данные или нет.

Comment: это должен определять не пользователь, а сам жава код