# Сортировка полученных данных из postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Есть одна таблица в postgresql, есть один пользователь, который будет просматривать все записи.

Как можно отсортировать так, чтобы когда пользователь второй или n-ый раз оправляет select запрос, он получал только новые записи?

PS: все запросы отправляются через java приложение.

Comment: Дополнить таблицу полем, в котором ставить пометку, что запись уже показывалась. Другие методы требуют больше знаний о структуре хранения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сортировать полученные из postgesql данные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820031/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-postgesql-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5)